# Manifest element must be declared

Tags: android, manifest

This error occurs in ic_launcher.xml file that located in mipmap-anydpi-v26 directory and I can not solve it even I tried to change its location.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.robpercival.listviewdemo">

<application android:allowBackup="true"
             android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>


</manifest >
```

similar problems occur with RelativeLayout and menu elements and I solve them by deleting ic_launcher files from drawable directory and creating new files in menu and layout directories. I am not sure but maybe these problems happen when android studio version is updated to 3.5.

Comment: I think you should delete v26 from end of directory

Comment: I tried to delete it but still the error

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you delete 'ic_launcher' file form drawable folder to solve RelativeLayout menu element problem,

but this file is linked in `/mipmap/ic_launcher/ic_launcher.xml` and `/mipmap/ic_launcher_round/ic_launcher_round.xml` file in mipmap folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
   <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

just delete 2 file

/mipmap/ic_launcher/ic_launcher.xml(anydpi-26)

/mipmap/ic_launcher_round/ic_launcher_round.xml(anydpi-26)

> Edit

**Or**,

Copy ic_launcher_round(xxxhdpi) to drawable folder.

and edit

/mipmap/ic_launcher/ic_launcher.xml(anydpi-26)

/mipmap/ic_launcher_round/ic_launcher_round.xml(anydpi-26)

like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_round" />
  <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_round" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

Comment: how I can delete ic_launcher and ic_launcher_round files? they are used in manifest file

Comment: Also, when I recreate ic_launcher_foreground and ic_launcher_background in drawable , the problem in menu and relativeLayout occur again

Comment: If your delete ic_launcher and ic_launcher_round there will be till remain 5 option mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxdpi so there is no problem. Or you can do another thing.. see the edited code...

Comment: I found that the code in ic_launcher files is uncompleted so, I create a new project and its run correctly.

Comment: It sounds good.... run correctly. I hope your previous project will also run correctly, if you do as answer. May be you are missing something.... By the way good luck...