# Android Studio 4.0.1 (Aug 2020), 'Element manifest must be declared' & 'Element resources must be declared' Error

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest, android-resources

Since the upgrade to 4.0, AS has been throwing both of these [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60359685/manifest-element-must-be-declared) and not allowing the build.

I have read the old solutions and found one [outside](https://www.android-examples.com/solve-element-selector-must-be-declared-error-in-android-studio/) of the forum that I thought I could adapt. Yet, nothing has solved this problem.

I have copied my manifest to a new manifest file. Also, I have uninstalled and reinstalled AS several times. Maybe I am not wiping the system clean enough...?

Anybody else in the same boat?

Any solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Nothing has fixed it. I'm contemplating reformatting the whole disk and starting over. Have you been able to fix it?